# How to show image in Angular 4 application read through laravel 5 rest api

Tags: laravel, angular, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am using Angular 4 frontend and Laravel 5 Rest API for my application. I save and read images in Laravel using below code

```
public function store(Request $request) {

    $file = $request->file('filefield');
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    Storage::disk('local')->put($file->getFilename().'.'.$extension,  File::get($file));
    $entry = new Image();
    $entry->mime = $file->getClientMimeType();
    $entry->original_filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $entry->filename = $file->getFilename().'.'.$extension;

    $entry->save();

    return response()->success(['image' => $entry]);

}

public function get(Image $image){

    $file = Storage::disk('local')->get($image->filename);

    return (new Response($file, 200))
          ->header('Content-Type', $image->mime);
}
```

This works fine. I am able to post and save image using Angular frontend. I am able to retrieve and see image using just the API i.e. if I open the URL myapplication/api/images/1 in the browser, I see the image.

But I am having issue retrieving and showing image using Angular
Here are the Angular code excerpts for the service, component

```
getImage(id: number): Promise<any> {
        return this._http.get(this.imageUrl + id)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response as any)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

This calls the correct URL e.g. http://myapplication/api/images/1

Service is called here in the component (hard coded image id just to test)

```
this.route.paramMap
  .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.packageService.getImage(1))
  .subscribe(image => this.image = image);
```

and this is the component HTML:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="{{ image }}"/>
```

But I get this error

```
unsafe:Response with status: 200 OK
```

How can I resolve this error and show the image in Angular 4 application received through Laravel REST API.